# Is there an R function for applying min() on all values of a whole column?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, apply

I don't mean like finding the min of a column. I mean comparing every value in a column to a number and extracting the minimum for comparison, preferably as a new column? Do I have to use loops, rapply/lapply, or can I do something with vectorisation? Example below.

Input:

| Column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Number for comparing in min: 2

Output:

| Column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but `pmax(Column, 2)` will get the second from the first frame above. (Related functions: `pmin`, and slightly-related `cummin` and `cummax`.)

Comment: It seems like it's working, but when I tried to assign it to a new column in a shinyapp renderTable function it says error replacement has 0 rows. in any case, thanks a lot for helping me discover the pmin function! definitely saved me a lot of time for writing loops...

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing outside of these two frames and the expression I suggested.

Comment: I was trying to do this:

table$min_hdg_lim_L <- pmin(table$hdg_lim_L,input) where input is the equivalent of the number 2 above, then I got the error .data.frame: replacement has 0 rows, data has 70.

Comment: Check the spelling of your objects and column names. For instance, if `hdg_lim_L` is not a column in the data.frame named `table`, then it will return `NULL`, and `pmin(NULL,2)` returns `numeric(0)` which cannot be assigned to the column of a frame with more than 0 rows.

Comment: ... and if you're in a `shiny` environment, the use of `input` in `pmin(table$hdg_lim_L,input)` is either a poor choice of an internal variable name, or it's a misuse of shiny's `input$` variable.

Comment: It's input$num in my code, but just ignored the $num part for simplicity sake... my bad! As for columns, I'm 100% sure hdg_lim_L is a column that has 70 rows in my dataframe, and although the first two are NA values but I don't think it should affect pmin. The only part not in my dataframe is the new column min_hdg_lim_L I'm trying to assign to.

Comment: Are you converting it to a number? Typically `input$...` variables are all strings, regardless if they are all digits. It sounds like this is a different question, though.

Comment: Nah, it's a numericInput...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, there are a few ways to do this. Here's a very `dplyr`ish way that works, but I don't think is the sexiest, necessarily:

```r
library(tidyverse)

input <- tibble(
    x = 1:3
)

mins_to_compare_across <- c(1,2,2)

input %>%
    mutate(mins_to_compare_across = mins_to_compare_across) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    transmute(
        x = min(
            c_across(
                c(
                    x,
                    mins_to_compare_across
                )
            )
        )
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here's a `purrr` way that I like a lot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

input <- tibble(
    x = 1:3
)

mins_to_compare_across <- c(1,2,2)

input %>%
    mutate(
        x = map2_dbl(
            x,
            mins_to_compare_across,
            ~ min(.x, .y)
        )
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>       x
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     1
#> 2     2
#> 3     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>